# Using jQuery Form plugin, how do I prevent form resubmission temporarily?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form) to install an event handler for form submission. However, I need to disable resubmission of the form until I receive an event that the server has finished processing. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by introducing a JavaScript variable `allowSubmit`, which is initially `true`. After form submission it is `false`, making my submission handler not do anything. When the server responds to the submission, `allowSubmit` is reset to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

will do the stuff

Comment: That doesn't handle other forms of form submission?? I can think of at least one, pressing Enter in a text field.

Comment: @aknuds1: no it won't. try it

Comment: If you by #submit refer to the submit button, I've already tried this technique and it doesn't stop me from submitting by pressing Enter in an input field.